# Как создать SQL запрос?

Tags: mysql, node.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть таблица, у которых одинаковый id_post. Нужно сделать так, что если добавить N количество записей у которых другой id_post (к примеру 2000), то должны удалиться все записи 1-ых id_post
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если добавить еще, то такой же процесс, но теперь 1-ые удаляются полностью

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Так вот, как это сделать, я понятия не имею

Comment: Совершенно неясно, о чём речь... пока только понятно, что это поле с дедлоками.

Comment: @Akina, было ( 4 записи по 100 ) + ( 2 записи по 2000) = 1 запись по 100 и 2 записи по 2000 // У 100 УДАЛИЛИ ВСЕ ЗАПИСИ КРОМЕ ПОСЛЕДНЕЙ

1 запись по 100 и 2 записи по 2000 + 4 записи по 3000 = 1 запись по 2000 и 4 записи по 3000 // У 100 УДАЛИЛИ ОСТАТОК, А У 2000 УДАЛИЛИ ВСЕ КРОМЕ ПОСЛЕДНЕЙ

Comment: Пиши хранимую процедуру, которая будет реализовывать сию странную логику. Хотя как по мне, то вот это безумное и спешное удаление - совершенно бессмысленно, гораздо проще просто не получать ненужные записи в запросе.